# Vertical Aligning with pseudo-element and weird characters

Tags: html, css

I am using the [Ghost Element](http://codepen.io/KatieK2/pen/ucwgi) CSS centering for an unknown child and am seeing some really weird behavior when the string has strange characters in it.

When I'm rendering a normal string my output looks like this:

[image: Normal]

And when I have a string with weird characters it looks like this:

[image: Problem]

Here's the string being rendered in the second example:

`The 2nd St. bridge waterfall is the best part of the show ✨ὤc✨ ὓ9ὓ9ὓ9ὓ9ὓ9ὓ9ὓ9ὓ9ὓ9ὓ9ὓ9ὓ9ὓ9ὓ9ὓ9 Great photo by @agarrini ὄfὄfὄf Thanks for tagging #Igerslouisville ὠ4 ὓ9ὓ9ὓ9ὓ9ὓ9ὓ9ὓ9ὓ9ὓ9ὓ9ὓ9ὓ9ὓ9ὓ9ὓ9`

HTML / CSS

```css
.text {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 5%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.text:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0;
}
.message {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://www.placehold.it/500" />
<div class="text">
  <div class="message">
    <p>The 2nd St. bridge waterfall is the best part of the show ✨ὤc✨ ὓ9ὓ9ὓ9ὓ9ὓ9ὓ9ὓ9ὓ9ὓ9ὓ9ὓ9ὓ9ὓ9ὓ9ὓ9 Great photo by @agarrini ὄfὄfὄf Thanks for tagging #Igerslouisville ὠ4 ὓ9ὓ9ὓ9ὓ9ὓ9ὓ9ὓ9ὓ9ὓ9ὓ9ὓ9ὓ9ὓ9ὓ9ὓ9</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is such a strange issue, I've never seen these characters causing such a layout issue before.

Comment: your class 'feed-item' has two closing quotes.  `<li class="feed-item"">`

Comment: if you're looking to place text over pictures i have a good solution for you.

Comment: @r00k whoops, just a typo on my part, not actually showing up on the actual site.

Comment: @JoshuaByer let's hear it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### The problem

The problem isn't caused by the characters themselves, it's caused by the long unbroken string of text. Replacing the characters with `a` has the same problem:

```css
.text {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: #F00;
}
.text:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background: #F90;
  width: 0;
}
.text p {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">

  <p>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</p>

</div>
```

### Solution

The solution is to break the long string in some way (preferably on the server side). In CSS you could break the long strings with [`word-wrap: break-word`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-wrap) (or the new standard `overflow-wrap` — [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=wordwrap)) and a suitable width:

```css
.text {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: #F00;
}
.text:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background: #F90;
  width: 0;
}
.text p {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 90%;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">

  <p>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</p>

</div>
```

Comment: `word-break: break-all;` is actually what ended up fixing it for me, weirdly enough.

Answer (score -1):

```
<div id ='myimage' class='image'>
<div class='text'>
This image was created by me 
 </div>

#myimage
{
 background-image: url("myimage.bmp");
 height:480px;
 width:640px;
 line-height: 480px;
}
.image
{
 text-align: center;
 vertical-align: middle;
}
.text
{
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: middle;
 line-height: normal;
 font-size:24px;
 font-weight:bold;
}
```